# Are files in the /public directory served via the rails stack?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm using nginx + phusion, I believe in the rails docs it says that if I put page caching on, then a html file is created and put the /public folder.

Does this mean that the phusion service won't have to put the request through the rails stack?

How is the file served then, just by nginx alone?

Answer (score 0):

Static assets are served directly by nginx, this includes page caches.

See bottom of: http://www.modrails.com/documentation.html

Comment: doc explains also the assets served directly by nginx if it runs under the user has permission to them. if this is the same user modrails and nginx works itself, it's enough condition serve static directly

Comment: you can take a look at oprimized nginx+passenger config [on gist.github.com](http://bit.ly/dNlnYN)

Answer (score 0):

From the Rails Guides:

> config.serve_static_assets configures Rails itself to serve static assets. Defaults to true, but in the production environment is turned off as the server software (e.g. Nginx or Apache) used to run the application should serve static assets instead.

The recommendation is not to turn this setting on in production. Let nginx serve it directly.